# how to send filtered paramter to a function in angular js?

Tags: angularjs

I want to send filtered date as parameter to my function, fetchData(), i tried something like this, but its giving errors. what is the correct way of doing it?

```
<button type="button" ng-click="gridDataCtrl.fetchData(selectedUser.name,myDate | date:'dd-MM-yyyy')">Refresh</button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do filter in controller

HTML:

```
<button type="button" ng-click="gridDataCtrl.fetchData(selectedUser.name,myDate)">Refresh</button>
```

In controller(make sure that you inject `$filter`):

```
vm.fetchData = function(name, date){
  date = $filter('date')(date, 'dd-MM-yyyy');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can filter inside of your gridDataCtrl.fetchData() callback.